# Load daily MySQL DB snapshots from S3 to snowflake

Tags: amazon-s3, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, data-migration

I have daily MySQL DB snapshots stored on S3. This daily DB snapshot is a backup of 1000 tables in our DB, using mysqldump, size is about 300M daily (stored 1 year of snapshots, which is about 110G).

Now we want to load these snapshots daily to snowflake for reporting purpose. How do we create tables in snowflake? Shall we create 1000 tables? Will snowflake be able to handle this scenario?

All comments are welcome. Thanks!

Comment: Having read the Snowflake documentation, what specific questions do you have about how to create tables? If you have 1000 source tables why are you asking if you should create 500 Snowflake tables? What, precisely, is the scenario you are asking if Snowflake can handle?

Comment: Sorry for the confusion. I've updated the question to be more specific. 

The scenario is we have some daily metrics to be calculated from daily snapshots of 1000 tables stored in S3 and we want to be able to do the same in Snowflake. 

In Snowflake, can we directly use or load daily snapshots of 1000 tables stored in S3 to complete these calculation in Snowflake (via stored procedures, etc.)? Shall we create 1000 tables to complete this task?

Our purpose is to avoid creating dimension or fact tables (typical data warehouse approach) to save cost at the beginning. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

One comment before I look at possible solutions: your statement "Our purpose is to avoid creating dimension or fact tables (typical data warehouse approach) to save cost at the beginning" is the sort of thinking that can get companies into real trouble. Once you build something and start using it, in 99% of cases you will be stuck with it - so not designing a proper, supportable, reporting solution (whether it is a Kimball model or something else) from the start is always a false economy. If you take a "quick and dirty" approach now you will regret it in a year's time.

With that out of the way, there seem to be 2 issues you need to address:

1. How to store your data
2. How to process your data (to produce you metrics and whatever else you want to do with it)

### Data Storage

(Probably stating the obvious) Any tables that you create to hold metrics or which will be accessed by BI tools (including direct SQL) I would hold in Snowflake - otherwise you wont get the performance that Snowflake can deliver and there is little point using Snowflake - you might as well be using Athena directly against your S3 buckets.

For your source tables (currently in S3), in an ideal world I would also copy them into Snowflake and treat S3 as your staging area - so once the data has been copied from S3 to Snowflake you can drop the data from S3 (or archive it or do whatever you want to it).

However, if you need the S3 versions of the data for other purposes (and so can't delete it once it has been copied to Snowflake) then rather than keep duplicate copies of the data you could create External Tables in Snowflake that point to your S3 buckets and don't require you to move the data into Snowflake. Query performance against External Tables will be worse than if the tables were within Snowflake, but performance may be good enough for your purposes - especially if they are "just" being used as data sources rather than for analytical queries.

### Computation

There are a number of options for the technologies you use to calculate your metrics - which one you choose is probably down to your existing skillset, cost, supportability, etc.

1. Snowflake functionality - Stored Procedures, External Functions (still in Preview rather than GA, I believe), etc.
2. External coding tools: anything that can connect to Snowflake and read/write data (e.g. Python, Spark, etc.)
3. ETL/ELT tool - probably overkill for your specific use case but if you are building a proper reporting platform that requires an ETL tool then obviously you could use this to create your metrics as well as move your data around

Hope this helps?